# How to fetch calender event from phone in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, calendar, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap.I want to fetch the calender events from phone.but it is in alert "[]"

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false);  

     function onDeviceReady()
    {       
     window.plugins.calendar.listEventsInRange("10/10/2013","11/11/2015",success,error);
    }

    function success (message)
    {
        alert("Success: " +JSON.stringify(message));

    }

    function error(err)
    {
    alert("Error :"+ err);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? If an error occurs, please post the exception and the expected result.

Comment: It is not showing any error. Just showing "Success: [] ". But same code when i run on different device it is listing events.